# Is putting string direct to the pointer (without declare static or dynamic space in RAM) good practice?

Tags: c

```
char* load_text(char* text, int how_many)
{
    char* result = 0;
    char* here = 0;

    result = fgets(text, how_many, stdin);
    if (result)
    {
        here = strchr(text, '\n');
        if (here)
            *here = '\0';
        else
            while (getchar() != '\n')
                continue;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This function is simple, send string from the keyboard and put to the pointer variable and then search new line '\n' in this string and remove in this place with null character '\0'
Then remove new line from function when you pressed ENTER

My question is:

Is it good to put string direct to the pointer from function fgets() to pointer *result?

Or is it a bad practice?

Because i searched a lot information about this problem
And many peaople told me:

Never put string direct to the pointer, which points to the random address in RAM without making static space or dynamic allocation in RAM !!!

I learn C programming language from Stephen Prat book "C Primer Plus, 6th Edition" and i founded this example in this book

From my point of view, I think putting strings directly to the random address RAM without static declare space for string or dynamic allocation is very bad idea

Correct me if i am wrong?
I think this example make really mess in RAM

I want know if my point of view is correct.

Comment: If `text` points to the first element of a character array of at least `how_many` elements, then it will work fine. Remember, even when you use an actual array, it will decay to a pointer to the first element of the array. In C the only way to pass actual arrays as arguments, even to standard functions, is through structures.

Comment: Tip: Nobody talks about "RAM" like that. It's just memory.

Comment: It's hard to give you a useful answer without seeing an example of how you expect this function to be called.

Comment: When I say that "it will work fine" in my previous comment, I meant the `fgets` call (and the `strchr` call as well). But the loop `while (getchar() != '\n')` will become an infinite loop if you hit the end of the file without getting a newline. You need to check against newline *and* `EOF`. And remember that `getchar` returns an `int`, which is very important when comparing against the `int` value `EOF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a notion that memory is associated with pointers. For example, in `int *p = malloc(3 * sizeof *p);`, some people say that memory is “allocated to `p`”. This is not correct. Memory is allocated, the address of that memory is returned, and that address is assigned to `p`, meaning that the value of `p` is set to that address. No ownership of the memory is associated with `p`, nor is any enduring relationships between `p` and the memory formed other than that `p` currently holds the address of the memory.

You could follow this with `int *q = p;` and `int *r = p;`, and then `p`, `q`, and `r` would have the same address, and none of them would have any privileged status over the others. They are simply variables that hold values.

In `result = fgets(text, how_many, stdin);`, the value returned by `fgets` is assigned to `result`. There is no need to allocate any memory for `result` to point to before this. In fact, doing so would be counterproductive, because the address assigned to `result` would be overwritten by `result = fgets(text, how_many, stdin);`.

> Is it good to put string direct to the pointer from function fgets() to pointer *result?

It is fine.

> And many peaople told me: Never put string direct to the pointer, which points to the random address in RAM without making static space or dynamic allocation in RAM !!!

You should never **use** a pointer before it has been assigned an appropriate address. For example, you should never use `*result`, as in `*result = x;` or `x = *result;`, before `result` has been set to pointer to an appropriate address.

`result = fgets(text, how_many, stdin);` sets `result` to an appropriate address, so it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

there is no simple answer - it all depends, but your function depends on the caller supplying a valid pointer and a valid length. But c coding is like that , you are at the mercy of your caller. Look at the `fgets` function, it has to depend on its caller providing valid arguments too

Answer (score 0):

This function has no responsibility to allocate memory, that has been pushed to the caller. If the caller does not allocate correctly when calling, this function will fail, but through no fault of its own.

Since you do check the result of `fgets` if there is an error you do return an error, so it all works out.

When you say this:

> Never put string direct to the pointer, which points to the random address in RAM without making static space or dynamic allocation in RAM !!!

I think what you mean is "never write to an uninitialized pointer", which is true. It does not mean "never put a string direct to the pointer" as that doesn't mean anything.

For example, if you had this:

```
char* x;

load_text(x, 100);
```

That is *undefined behaviour*, no allocation was made, but it's not the fault of the `load_text` function itself. This is just buggy code that needs to be fixed.